# Is it possible to sort rows in a Microsoft WORD table without the data being sorted alphabetically, alphanumerically or in date order?

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-word

It is a tricky question to ask, and I have not been able to even attempt using VBA code to try and figure this out. Using Table.Sort does not assist. Here is an example below if you are confused with what I require:

```
BEFORE            AFTER
rice              rice
pea               rice
apple             pea
vegetable         pea
vegetable         apple
pea               apple
apple             vegetable
rice              vegetable
orange            orange
```

As you can see above, although the data in the second column is sorted in an orderly fashion, it is not alphabetical. Is it possible to do this without having to place numbers in front of text in a column of a table then sort? Or without me having to do it all manually? My example above is a simple one, and for larger amounts of information, it would not be practical to do this manually. I can do what I require in EXCEL using formulas but I really need the word processing abilities of WORD rather than EXCEL.

Comment: can you place your table into an Excel sheet temporarily, run the sort you want, and then bring it back into Word?

Comment: Hi Charles,  I hope all is well with you and many thanks for taking the time to reply to my question.  Because I work on the table continuously in real time with the order constantly changing, it would not be practical doing it this way. However, I received an answer to my question around 16 hours ago (really quick) with code that I did not have the capability of compiling. But thank you very much for taking the time to reply to me: whenever I have been looking for assistance on coding, I have seen your name pop up consistently.  Your answers to other's queries have helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I had some free time, so I made a program to sort a table in Word based on my understanding of your sorting rules.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Call CustomSort(ThisDocument.Tables(1))
End Sub

Sub CustomSort(sortTable As Table)
    'Create an array that contains the table values
    Dim Items() As String
    ReDim Items(1 To sortTable.Rows.Count, 1 To sortTable.Columns.Count)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To sortTable.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To sortTable.Columns.Count
            Items(i, j) = Left(sortTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text, Len(sortTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text) - 2) 
            'removes the extra characters at the end of a cell - credit to Timothy Rylatt
        Next j
    Next i

    'Sort the table
    Dim r As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Items, 1) - 2
        For r = i + 2 To UBound(Items, 1)
            If Items(i, 1) = Items(r, 1) Then Call ArrayRowShift(Items, r, i + 1)
        Next r
    Next i
    
    'Output the table
    For i = 1 To sortTable.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To sortTable.Columns.Count
            sortTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = Items(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
Sub ArrayRowShift(ByRef Arr As Variant, RowIndex As Long, MoveTo As Long)
    'For 2D arrays, takes an array row, moves it to the specified index, returns the shifted array
    If RowIndex = MoveTo Then Exit Sub
    Dim tmpRow() As Variant
    ReDim tmpRow(LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2))
    For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
        tmpRow(j) = Arr(RowIndex, j)
    Next j
    If RowIndex < MoveTo Then
        For i = RowIndex + 1 To MoveTo
            For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
                Arr(i - 1, j) = Arr(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    Else
        For i = RowIndex To MoveTo + 1 Step -1
            For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
                Arr(i, j) = Arr(i - 1, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
        Arr(MoveTo, j) = tmpRow(j)
    Next j
End Sub
```

I take the table text into an array, re-arrange things in the array using VBA, then paste it back into the table. It works for any size of table in word (1D or 2D).

If you want to adjust the sorting rules, the line you need to edit is `If Items(i, 1) = Items(r, 1) Then`. You may want to add `LCase` around both, to remove case-sensitivity. Or `Trim`, to make sure excess white-space isn't preventing matches.

Comment: Toddleson, I would just like to say............you are an absolute God!!!!! This code that you compiled so soon after I posted my question works like a dream!!! I had been pondering how to do this for about a year with no one able to assist. me. I cannot thank you enough for what you have done!

Comment: Just a couple more things: every time you use the macro it adds an additional line of space to each cell. how do I prevent it from doing that and how do you keep the original formatting of the cells after you use the macro?

Comment: @KevinO - the problem stems from storing `sortTableCell(i,j).Range.Text` in the array. For a table cell `Range.Text` includes two non-printing characters, a paragraph mark and an end of cell mark. You can verify this by creating a document with an empty table and typing `?Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Text)` in the Immediate window. To fix the issue simply remove the extra characters - `Left(sortTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text, Len(sortTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text) - 2)`

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. I am a novice in this field and find all this fascinating. I have a lot to learn and I really appreciate the time you all have taken to explain and assist me in my predicament. It took me a while to get my head around your explanation but the light bulb moment finally took place!

Comment: @KevinO my code has been updated to resolve this issue. If this code answers your question, I would appreciate the green checkmark on my post. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies, Toddleson for not getting back to you: I have just seen your post. I have tested the code and it works perfectly! I cannot thank you enough for your assistance!

Comment: As a new user, I am unsure as to how to tick the well deserved green check mark against this post.

Answer (score 0):

For this code to work, you need [this reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGlm9.jpg).
This is being run from Word VBA, not Excel.

```
Sub SortingSortOf()
Dim XL As Excel.Application, WB As Excel.Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet, MatchCol As Excel.Range, Tbl As Table

    Set XL = Excel.Application
    Set WB = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\To\Workbook\With\YourTable.xlsm") ' or.xlsx
    Set WS = WB.Sheets("NameOfTableSheet")
    
    ' places a sort value one column to the right of the current data
    Set MatchCol = WS.UsedRange.Columns(WS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1)
    
    ' change this to whatever column holds your sort value
    MatchCol.Formula = "=Match(A1, A:A, 0)"
    
    ' i'm assuming you have some sort of header
    WS.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=MatchCol, Header:=xlYes
    
    'optional, unless you want the sort number displayed in the table
    MatchCol.Delete
    
    ' or wherever you want. doesn't have to be paragraph 1
    If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        ' for some reason it doesn't overwrite an existing table
        ' so this will delete it first (even if there is more than one)
        For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Tables
            Tbl.Delete
        Next Tbl
    End If
    WS.UsedRange.Copy
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Paste
    
    ' putting false on close should prevent the save changes dialog,
    ' but there seems to be an excel bug, so shutting off alerts
    XL.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.Close , False
    XL.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Stacks. Thank you for getting back to me and taking the time to compile this code for me. It is a real honour receiving this code from you.  It took me a while to get my head around this (I had to play around with it), but I am getting a better understanding of VBA. Again thank you very much for your assistance.