# Excel VBA (very slow) If condition is met then move entire row to the bottom

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

just looking for guidance on how I might speed up one of my VBA query's (if condition is met then move the entire row to the bottom)

This is what  have so far and it works, but its really slow (sheet with only approx 400 rows takes approx 5 mins to run)

```
Sub Running_Sort()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim lr As Long

lrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lrow To 6 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 15).Value = "Survey" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 15)).Cut
        Sheets("Running").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Insert
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've turned off screen updating and also changed from copying the entire row to just the columns that I need but they haven't made much of a difference.

Sorry if i sound idiotic, I'm self taught and still learning daily so feel free to school me if I've made a blatant error or missed something obvious:)

Comment: I believe you just need to pause the auto calculation `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before row moving and then restore it afterwards.

Comment: Try adding `MsgBox lrow` before your loop. Is the value as expected (400)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast general approach would be Sort the table rather than Cut/Paste.

Steps would be

- Add a (temporary) formula to an otherwise unused column, that orders the data as you wish.
  In this case I'd suggest `=ROW()+IF(RC[-1]="Survey",2000000,0)`
- Sort the table based on this formula value
  Sort can be done with

  - Excels Sort functionality (manually or with code)
  - The Dynamic Array formula `SORT` (again, manually or with code)
  - A coded sort algorithm of your choice
- Remove the formula

You could do this manually, or code it, as you see fit.

As an example, here's a Sub that uses the Dynamic Array formula `SORT`
It assumes

- there is no data to the right of the table
- there are no formula *in* the table. (If there are, they will be overwitten with their values)
- there are no formula that *refer to* the table.  (If there are, they may or may not end up refering to the correct data after the Sub is run)

A test run of this code on 50,000 rows ran in <2s

```
Sub MoveBySortTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rTable As Range
    Dim Reordered As Variant
    
    Dim TableTopLeftCell As Range
    Dim TableTopRightCell As Range
    Dim KeyWord As String
    
    KeyWord = "Survey"
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or specify the required sheet
    
    ' set up parameters to define the table range
    Set TableTopLeftCell = ws.Cells(6, 4)  'D6
    Set TableTopRightCell = ws.Cells(TableTopLeftCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    ' or
    'Set TableTopLeftCell = ws.Cells(6, 15)
    
    ' Get reference to table range, plus one column
    Set rTable = ws.Range(TableTopRightCell, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, TableTopLeftCell.Column).End(xlUp))
    Set rTable = rTable.Resize(, rTable.Columns.Count + 1)
    
    ' Add a formula to sort by
    rTable.Columns(rTable.Columns.Count).Formula2R1C1 = "=ROW()+IF(RC[-1]=""" & KeyWord & """,2000000,0)"

    ' Sort the table
    Reordered = ws.Evaluate("=SORT(" & rTable.Address & "," & rTable.Columns.Count & ")")
    
    ' Place sorted data onto sheet
    rTable.Value2 = Reordered
    
    ' Clear the formula
    rTable.Columns(rTable.Columns.Count).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably meant `Set TableTopRightCell = ws.Cells(6, 15)`. In the first `Set rTable...`, you are illustrating that e.g. `B1:A2` will result in the same range as `A1:B2`. Is that on purpose? Shouldn't it be `.Resize(, rTable.Columns.Count + 1)`? The 'formula line' is raising `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error` on my end.

Comment: @VBasic2008 `columns.count + 1` yes you're right  (edited).  `B1:A2` vs A1:B2` yes, they produce the same range, and it's a quite useful technique at times.   Re the RTE, the formula works for me in Excel 365.  Do you use a version that supports the `Formula2` variants? Other than that I can't see why it would error for you.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2019. I guess that would be the reason behind it. On the other hand, why is `Formula2R1C1` even an option then? Anyway, It's a great idea and I'll try to figure out a way to do it in my Excel version i.e. I can use the '`A1` `.Formula`'. I wrote an `AutoFilter` version, but it took an unacceptable 40s for 50,000 records.

Comment: Chris your a star! very clean solution that does exactly what i need it to! i had avoided sort because i had other columns sorted and thought it would mess them up, i never even considered doing it like this! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`Insert` is a slow operation in general because Excel has to check all the data and reassign addresses to every moved cell. To make this code run faster, you'll want to rewrite it as an array operation and not a worksheet operation.

You can quickly grab values from a sheet like `MyArray = MySheet.Range("A1:Z50")` and then paste back from an array to a Worksheet like `MySheet.Range("A1:Z50") = MyArray`.

Here is how I would do that:

```vb
Sub Running_Sort()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    With Sheets("Running")
        lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Save the Worksheet Area as a Range
        Dim TableRange As Range
        Set TableRange = .Range(.Cells(6, 4), .Cells(lrow, 15))
        
        'Grab all values from the Worksheet into a 2D Array of size (1 To Rows.Count, 1 to Columns.Count)
        Dim ValArray() As Variant
        ValArray = TableRange.Value
    End With
    
    For i = UBound(ValArray) To LBound(ValArray) Step -1
        'column 15 is now 12 because the array starts counting columns from 1 instead of 4
        '(15 - 4 + 1) = 12
        If ValArray(i, 12) = "Survey" Then ArrayRowShift ValArray, i, UBound(ValArray)
    Next

    TableRange.Value = ValArray

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub ArrayRowShift(ByRef Arr As Variant, RowIndex As Long, MoveTo As Long)
    'For 2D arrays, takes an array row, moves it to the specified index, returns the shifted array
    If RowIndex = MoveTo Then Exit Sub
    Dim tmpRow() As Variant
    ReDim tmpRow(LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2))
    For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
        tmpRow(j) = Arr(RowIndex, j)
    Next j
    If RowIndex < MoveTo Then
        For i = RowIndex + 1 To MoveTo
            For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
                Arr(i - 1, j) = Arr(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    Else
        For i = RowIndex To MoveTo + 1 Step -1
            For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
                Arr(i, j) = Arr(i - 1, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    For j = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2)
        Arr(MoveTo, j) = tmpRow(j)
    Next j
End Sub
```

ArrayRowShift is the function I wrote for a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69588241/14608750). To move rows of a 2D array into a new position.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I have placed comment for reason. One warning about your method is that if the cells you cut contains formulas, it may ruin the data in the "Running" worksheet.

```
Sub Running_Sort()
    Debug.Print "Running_Sort() Started: " & Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Long, lCalcMode As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    lCalcMode = Application.Calculation ' Stores original setting
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' Pause auto calculating
    
    lRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = lRow To 6 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 15).Value = "Survey" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 15)).Cut
            Sheets("Running").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Insert
        End If
        DoEvents ' Typically solves Excel being halted for large amount of entries in loop
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Application.Calculation = lCalcMode ' Restores original setting
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print "Running_Sort() Finished: " & Now
End Sub
```