# Is it possible to order a table in MICROSOFT WORD with at least two rows and two columns without sorting alphanumerically without adopting EXCEL VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

BEFORE

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| apple | cabbage |
| pear | carrot |
| apple | aubergine |
| apple | potato |
| pear | yam |
| orange | marrow |

AFTER

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| apple | cabbage |
| apple | aubergine |
| apple | potato |
| pear | carrot |
| pear | yam |
| orange | marrow |

Is it possible to sort a table in Microsoft WORD in the way I have set out above? I had asked a similar question in 2021 which was solved for a table with only one column which worked a treat using Microsoft VBA (and without having to resort to utilising EXCEL).

My Microsoft Word VBA skills have marginally improved since the last question and the person who answered my question time (Toddleston) was a great help. I am unable to work out how to deal with this new issue.

When I attempted a table with more than two columns, although it arranged the first column in the way I wanted, it kept on changing the order of the second column (please see the link to my previous question ([Is it possible to sort rows in a Microsoft WORD table without the data being sorted alphabetically, alphanumerically or in date order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586950/is-it-possible-to-sort-rows-in-a-microsoft-word-table-without-the-data-being-sor))) which I did not want.

Answer (score 0):

Provided code sort the first table in the ActiveDocument. The 2nd column keeps the order as source table. The logic is:

- Loading data from table
- Loadind data into Dictionary object
- Sort unqiue list (Dict's key) of the 1st column
- Update table with sorted data

**Note**: it doesn't support a table with any merged cells.

btw, I think `AFTER` table in OP is incorrect, `orage` should be on top of `pear`.

```vb
Sub SortTableInWord()
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim aData(), Temp
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim RowsCnt As Long, c As Range
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    RowsCnt = oTable.Rows.Count
    ' Loading data from table
    ReDim aData(1 To RowsCnt, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To RowsCnt ' Update if the table has header
        For j = 1 To 2
            Set c = oTable.Cell(i, j).Range
            aData(i, j) = ActiveDocument.Range(c.Start, c.End - 1).Text
        Next j
    Next i
    Dim Dic As Object, aKey, aItem, k
    ' Loading data into Dic
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = 1 To RowsCnt
        Temp = aData(i, 1)
        If Dic.Exists(Temp) Then
            Dic(Temp) = Dic(Temp) & "|" & aData(i, 2)
        Else
            Dic(Temp) = aData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    aKey = Dic.keys
    ' Sort data in the first column
    ' OP doesn't need sorting data on the first column
'    aKey = Dic.keys
'    For i = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
'        For j = i + 1 To Dic.Count - 1
'            If aKey(i) = aKey(j) Then
'                Temp = aKey(i)
'                aKey(i) = aKey(j)
'                aKey(j) = Temp
'            End If
'        Next j
'    Next i
    ' Update table
    j = 1
    For i = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
        aItem = Split(Dic(aKey(i)), "|")
        For k = 0 To UBound(aItem)
            oTable.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = aKey(i)
            oTable.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = aItem(k)
            j = j + 1
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: taller_ExcelHome,, my apologies for not getting back to you earlier: I have been away from my computer, I have tested your vba and the second column works. I may not have been clear regarding the issue: I did not want the the first column or second column to be sorted alphabetically or alphanumerically. Are you able to address this?

Comment: I'm lost. May I know what's the logic of  the first column's order?  apple - pear - orange do you want to keep the output as the same order of its showing up in source table?

Comment: Hi taller_ExcelHome. I just wanted to thank you very much for your vba. I have tweaked what you did very slightly (for the 'Sort data in the first column' part - .....If aKey(i) > aKey(j) Then...). I changed the '>' sign to an '=" sign and now it works like a dream!!! I cannot thank you enough - this has been issue for me for such a long time and you manged to assist me in solving this really, really quickly!!

Comment: If you don't need sort data, you can remove the section `' Sort data in the first column
`

Comment: If you use your formula with the tweak, it will make what I wanted clear. It is difficult to explain. i wanted the groupings but in the order them come in the first column without the groupings being sorted alphabetically or alphanumerically.

Comment: I have tested it with tweaked formula. I'm sure you don't need the sorting section. Please try the updated code. You'll obtain the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ embedded Word's sorting feature:

```
  Selection.Tables(1).Select
  Selection.Sort ExcludeHeader:=False, FieldNumber:="Column 1", _
    SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending, _
    FieldNumber2:="", SortFieldType2:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder2:= _
    wdSortOrderAscending, FieldNumber3:="", SortFieldType3:= _
    wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder3:=wdSortOrderAscending, Separator:= _
    wdSortSeparateByCommas, SortColumn:=False, CaseSensitive:=False, _
    LanguageID:=wdEnglishUS, SubFieldNumber:="Paragraphs", SubFieldNumber2:= _
    "Paragraphs", SubFieldNumber3:="Paragraphs"
End Sub
```

To customize the sorting order, you can add another column with sorting key to the table. You can do it manually or programmatically.

In the programmatical way, temporary add a utility column, fill it out with sorting keys (you should have a rule to generate a key since you ask to not sort alphanumerically), perform sorting by the key column as provided above, then delete this utility column.